# How do I find text with yanked text on vim?

Tags: vim

Let us say that I yanked the following word:
**Cheese**.
Now I want to find **Cheese** within a text document. I hit the forward slash key(/)... and this is where I end.
Is there a way to search with Yanked word? Also, is there a way you can use yanked words in substitution(s:/yanked/beef/g)?

Comment: You should really accept CMS's answer at this point. It's been five years.

Comment: Hey man, it's been 9 years, better late than never. I'm sure CMS is waiting for your approval.

Comment: @RoyalPie Come on, it's been 11 years!

Answer (score 129):

The most recently yanked text will be stored in the `0` and `"` registers (if no register was explicitly specified e.g. by `"xy`).

Then you can paste the text of any that register in the last line (either in search mode <kbd>/</kbd> or in last line command mode <kbd>:</kbd> ) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, where `X` is the register you want to paste.

For example:

<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Will paste the contents of the register `0` in the forward search command pattern.

Comment: Thank you, you've answered my question.

Comment: @RoaylPie717 - If your question was answered, you should accept the answer rather than simply leave a comment saying so. (I realize this question is 2 years old, but here's to hoping...)

Answer (score 35):

1. yank the text
2. press <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>: open the search history

<kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>: paste the yanked text on the command line and search